# pyspark sql: how to count the row with mutiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, bigdata, row, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this after some operations;

```
df_new_1 = df_old.filter(df_old["col1"] >= df_old["col2"])
df_new_2 = df_old.filter(df_old["col1"] < df_old["col2"])

print(df_new_1.count(), df_new_2.count())
>> 10, 15
```

I can find the number of rows individually like above by calling `count()`. But how can I do this using `pyspark sql` `row` operation. i.e aggregating by row. I want to see the result like this;

```
Row(check1=10, check2=15)
```

Comment: Show us the pyspark code you have written so far.

Comment: Here it is @J_H, this is what I tried; df= df_new_1.groupBy("col1").agg({"col1":"count"}).collect().. but not giving the answer. for example to test condition1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged pyspark-sql, you can do the following:

```
df_old.createOrReplaceTempView("df_table")

spark.sql("""

    SELECT sum(int(col1 >= col2)) as check1
    ,      sum(int(col1 < col2)) as check2
    FROM df_table

""").collect()
```

Or use the API functions:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df_old.agg(
    expr("sum(int(col1 >= col2)) as check1"), 
    expr("sum(int(col1 < col2)) as check2")
).collect()
```